# How to shuffle in Jtable

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I have a JTable which contains TableModel(all my data). The JTable has multiple rows and columns. I need to shuffle the rows randomly. I understand I can do that with

```
Collections.shuffle(some list from TableModel);
```

But I dont know how to get the list from the existing JTable which had TableModel.

on somebodies suggestion, I  tried this

```
RowSorter<? extends TableModel> sorter = mDocListTable.getRowSorter();
    ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey> list = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();

    list.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.DESCENDING));

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    sorter.setSortKeys(list);
```

but didnt work.

Comment: I believe one approach would be to create a custom [`RowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html).  `RowSorter` was designed with the intent of using a column header as a sort key, so there's some excess overhead that you won't necessarily need, but the `convertRowIndexToModel(int index)` and `convertRowIndexToView(int index)` methods should do what you want; simply creating a mapping of the list of integers `[0, 1, ..., getRowCount()]`, to the same integers but shuffled.  The convert to view method would return the mapped value.

Comment: Though if you actually want the table in the model modified (not just the view), you could also just use `moveRow(int start, int end, int to)` in [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).

Comment: can you please elaborate on "simply creating a mapping of the list of integers [0, 1, ..., getRowCount()], to the same integers but shuffled". a small example would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work?

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.getDataVector().sort((Object o1, Object o2) -> Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

**Edit:**

For `Java-7` and since `.sort()` was not implemented until `Java-8`, a 2nd (and maybe more readable) option could be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
Collections.shuffle(model.getDataVector());
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

This cannot be reverted.

Comment: This is better than my answer was.  I've deleted my answer, and recommend this instead.

Comment: Do note though that this requires a version of Java that supports Lambda expressions (IE: Java 8).

Comment: What would be Object o1, Object o2

Comment: @user1631306 the rows to be compared by the `Comparator`, but since you just need a random result, you don't need it I guess

Comment: a.getDataVector().sort((null) -> Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1);  like this?

Comment: @user1631306 Those are the parameters of the [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) implementation of the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) being passed into the `sort` method.  Basically, any functional interface (Interfaces containing 1 method annotated with @FunctionalInterface) can be implemented using lambda expressions, which take the form of `(Args) -> action`.  It simply prevents you from having to create new anonymous inner objects (less verbose).

Comment: You will still need to pass in the objects: `.sort((null) -> ...` will not work.  What's happening here is that the method `sort(T t1, T t2)` is being defined by the lambda expression (where `T` is of type `Object` in this case).  I recommend taking a look into the [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation Javadoc (which `Comparator` uses, and hence allows the lambda expression to be defined in `sort()`).

Comment: it seems complicated to me. can we talk on chat?

Comment: I'm unable to chat currently unfortunately.  Also, I'm realizing I misspoke above; it should read `sort(Comparator)`, not `sort(T t1, T t2)`.  That's probably not helping the confusion.

Comment: Let me rewind; I might've made this way more complicated than it needs to be.  Lambda expressions provide the ability to dynamically implement single-method interfaces using less verbosity.  Where it says `(Object o1, Object o2) -> Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1` above, that's the **exact same** as saying `new Comparator<Object>() { @Override public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1}}`  you could instead use the latter if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://ideone.com/Nw7Bfw) that hopefully can make that clear.

Comment: unfortunately, I am using java 7 and cant move to 8 right now

Comment: @user1631306 added java 7 equivalent, also, in Ironcache example there is a Java8/java7 equivalent of this

Comment: Actually, looking at it now, `sort()` wasn't added to `Vector` until Java 8 (see [Java 7 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) vs. [Java 8 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)).  Instead of using `model.getDataVector().sort(...)`, you would need to use `Collections.sort(model.getDataVector(), ...)`, where `...` is kept the same in both cases, and `Collections` is coming from Guava.

Comment: I used Java-7 one, but I dont see any changes in the order of the elements of the model, before and after shuffling. I checked the content of model by model.getValueAt(3, 3) and they are same.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/wvP2rG).  Did you try it multiple times?  Shuffling could very easily result in content ending up in the same place.  Also, make sure you put in the `model.fireTableDataChanged()` call; it lets the `JTable` know that the `TableModel` changed.

Comment: When I check model.getDataVector().isEmpty(), it returns true to me. Though I am able to get that data is I do model.getValueAt(3, 3) and all... Also, I have AbstractTableModel and I am casting it to defaultTableModel

Comment: I'd recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the behavior you're seeing.  I can't reproduce it, and the answer as listed works for me, so I can't really help you get further without knowing more about the problem.